# Как делается псевдографический интерфейс в консоли?

Tags: c++, консоль

Решил создать консольный файловый менеджер и оформить его наподобие FARa.

Какие функции и библиотеки надо использовать, да и с чего вообще нужно начинать?

Comment: Можно предложить разве что смотреть исходники FARа, MC.

Comment: Зависит от того, под какую платформу вы хотите разрабатывать. Консоль в unix и windows управляется разным набором API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужны функции управления консолью. Поскольку C++ предоставляет лишь потоковый ввод-вывод (а этого **не** достаточно для ваших целей), вам придётся отказаться от использования `cin`/`cout`, и управлять консолью напрямую.

Здесь, к сожалению, вам придётся разделить ваш Windows- и Linux-специфический код.

Под Windows вам нужны [консольные функции WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Наверное, проще всего будет просто напрямую обращаться к [консольному буферу](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), который предоставляет символы на экране как просто прямоугольный массив из символов и их атрибутов.

Под Linux- (и вообще Unix-)платформой вам понадобится библиотека [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/), которая предоставляет аналогичную функциональность.

Если вы пишете кроссплатформенную программу, вам придётся сделать уровень абстракции над системно-зависимыми библиотеками, и работать с ним в основной программе.

Удачи!

Comment: Но можно и несколько иначе. Один процесс -- UI делаем на tcl/tk, а второй -- сишная часть,  общается с ним по pipe как с консолью. / (один мой коллега уже как лет 20 назад в качестве тренировки перед программированием UI мониторинга-управления  большой вычислительной сети для заказчика сделал такой аналог Нортона  для \*nix).

Comment: >вам придётся отказаться от использования cin/cout
а вот кстати почему нельзя использовать обычные функции вывода и ncurses?
Я хотел использовать ncurses для простого случая  но как посмотрел что они мне пытаются впарить, решил обойтись подручными способами.
https://github.com/zenden2k/image-uploader/blob/1.3.2/Source/CLI/ConsoleUtils.cpp
не знаю будет ли это везде нормально работать

Comment: @avp: Ого! Ну или так, но при этом `#ifdef` скрыт в коде tk.  В общем, это такая графическая библиотека как бы. Мне кажется, это претендует на отдельный ответ.

Comment: @zenden2k: Ну, из-за буферизации. Код потокового ввода-вывода не рассчитывает, что с ним параллельно будет работать ещё кто-нибудь, и утянет у него очередной символ. Ну и всякие хаки типа `ungetc` явно не рассчитаны на взаимодействие с посторонними.

Comment: @VladD, вряд ли мне стоит сейчас реально рекомендовать автору такой вариант (он же (если заинтересуется) наверняка захочет детали для винды, а этого я сходу не знаю), а ответ, он как-то обязывает...

Answer (score 4):

[image: TurboVision]

[Для этого можно попробовать использовать TurboVision](http://tvision.sourceforge.net)

Comment: ничоси, даже юникод поддерживается?

Comment: @zenden2k: По примерам видно поддержку UTF-8

Comment: Хех :) 20 лет назад им пользовался :)

Comment: Вот только будет ли он работать под *nix?  Скорее, нет, чем да.

Comment: @Aleks G: This port is a port of the C++ version for the DOS, FreeBSD, Linux, QNX, Solaris and Win32 platforms. Это уже на совести тех авторов которые портировали TurboVision на другие платформы.